# Why aren't users suspected of multiple voting irregularities suspended indefinitely?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1917782/ipatel

I see in this one's [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1917782/ipatel?tab=reputation), just on the first page:

[image]

Pretty clear what's going on. Why isn't a user like that removed indefinitely, instead of just

> This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The
>   suspension period ends on Jul 10 at 10:48.

You have to be pretty low to do these kind of things, but also the community and its moderators should do everything to discourage this.

Comment: Read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: @bjb568 And with most of the reasons provided there, I agree with a timed suspension. But this is something fundamental that disrupts the reputation fundamentals of SO.

Comment: @Leo: Yes, and they were caught (as they always are) and it was cleaned up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Doesn't it just give a motivation to continue finding "better" ways to game the system?

Comment: @LeoNatan: a permanent suspension will only lead to ban evasion. There are only so many ways you can game the system, and they all are sussed out sooner or later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, but then reputation would be 10, not whatever they had before. That's pretty discouraging to reputation whores.

Comment: @LeoNatan and that can be motivation for *more* gaming, not less.

Comment: Taken to extremes: desperate people do desperate things. Maximum sentences lead to *more* crime as you deny all option to reform.  Banning gamers forever brings them back more determined to not be caught, it is not a solution.

Comment: @Martijn A philosopher would argue to remove the game entirely. `;-)`

Comment: @Leo Delete SE? Suicide?

Comment: @bjb Oh dear, "SO" is what I meant

Comment: I found this now, June 2017, and it's ironic because that user is now in the top 1%, so I guess the user was rehabilitated, which is a good case for future debates.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because we always hold out hope for the rehabilitation of users. We give people repeated chances to reform their behavior after being educated about what they did wrong. Many, many people never repeat the troubling behavior after being warned and go on to become very productive members of the site. You would be surprised at the number of candidates in the previous election who were once warned about breaking site rules like this.

In cases of voting fraud, once the sock puppet accounts are removed and anomalous votes invalidated, all of the detrimental affects to the system will have been removed. Any improper unicorn points they amassed evaporate, and the artificially high votes on their posts return to normal. All that's left is to make sure this doesn't happen again, thus the warnings and temporary suspensions.

Suspensions are primarily intended to put a short hold on troubling behavior and to get someone to pay attention, not as a punitive measure. In fact, over the last year or so I've been experimenting with just warning, not even suspending, users who commit voting fraud. Suspensions can sometimes lead to people leaving the site permanently, or for them to flip out and become an even worse problem. A gentle, private warning to a user is often enough to get them to feel bad about what they did and to nudge them to become a productive member of the site.

My goal is not to punish people for misbehaving, it's simply to make sure that the site is kept clean and that visitors can trust the honesty of the voting system. Had we outright banned anyone who was suspected of voting fraud, we would have lost many people who went on to be great contributors.

Comment: How can you be sure that you have removed all offending accounts though. I have seen `they were caught (as they always are)` a lot but how could you possibly know that you have caught them ? Removing blatantly obvious upvoting accounts is easy enough, but what about someone who uses accounts as extras to their normal one. All a timed suspension teaches is that there are little to no repercussions to ruining others experience of the site.

Comment: @Jidder - There almost certainly are fake accounts that we and the system have missed. We try to handle the worst cases, and have very good tools for identifying those trying to pull this off. Once an account has been brought to our attention, it's easy for us to see other accounts they may have created (even if they think they are clever in hiding these). Again, our goal is to stop this behavior first (which a timed suspension can do if a warning did not suffice), and then prevent it in the future. Nothing we do can ever be perfect at finding these and dealing with them, but it works well.