# When/why would voting fraud NOT result in a suspension?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, sock-puppets

I recently encountered what appeared to be a straightforward case of sock puppetry and voting fraud: first, the OP accepted a nonsense answer. When that was deleted as abusive, the OP accepted another answer. The second accepted answer was literally two sentences long, but it received 5 votes in under 15 minutes (presumably from the OP's sock puppets), even though the question was over a month old and not in a major tag.

I flagged it for moderator intervention. The flags were marked helpful and the posts were deleted. However, the poster didn't appear to have been suspended (in spite of making multiple obvious attempts to commit voting fraud).

Out of curiosity, under what circumstances would someone *not* get suspended for voting fraud and why?

Comment: Brad covers this in the third paragraph of his answer to [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261196/why-arent-users-suspected-of-multiple-voting-irregularities-suspended-indefinit) (although it's about repeat offenders).

Comment: @BoltClock How is it decided who will and who won't be suspended? Is Brad's answer implying that if - and only if - someone doesn't listen to the warning they'll get suspended (i.e. that first-time offenders are usually not suspended)?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. The UI still defaults to the usual 7-days-on-first-offense, though, so withholding the initial suspension is often still a conscious decision.

Comment: About 97% of the time at least, very rough guess.  SO users have to learn that cheating doesn't work.  They usually get it quickly when they see phantom rep disappear again, only a few hardy souls try it a second or third time.  Mods use the slammer only for repeated attempts.