# Do sock-puppeteers get to keep rep from answers accepted by their sock-puppet account?

Tags: discussion, voting, deleted-users, sock-puppets

I'll keep it hypothetical for now, but it relates to a real situation.

In this case, the sock-puppeteer is temporarily suspended (common practice, [it seems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261203/3367799)) and the sock-puppet(s) is (are) deleted.

#### The fraudulent routine

Suppose a user has a sock-puppet account. They use the sock-puppet account to ask questions. They then answer with their real account and (eventually) accept their own answer from their sock-puppet (to yield the 15 reputation points).

#### Flags from a suspicious user & swift moderator action

Another user sees and reports this. The mods take quick action and remove the sock-puppet. This means the (up)votes from the sock-puppet are made void.

#### The ticks (and the actual question)

Much like the [arachnid ticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick#Relationship_with_humans), accepted answer ticks don't seem to disappear easily (after account deletion). That's actually what my question is about.

Do those answer ticks disappear after some time? Are mods going to remove those answer ticks manually (seems rather tedious work)?

Or is it somehow accepted that those answer ticks and (associated rep?) remain? That seems like a bad policy as the benefits reaped should not remain after the sock-puppeteer is caught.

Comment: If it's accept-based vote fraud, I think they destroy the accounts in most cases. The accept stays, but destroyed accounts can't exactly have rep. If the main account is the one that gets the accept, there's usually suspensions, where repeated behavior results in that. Maybe mods can remove rep somehow?

Comment: @Zoe in the case I'm looking at, without disclosing who it is (not sure if that's acceptable to do here) it reads: *"This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends in 7 days."* Given that the message specifies the reason for suspension, I think this isn't just a one-time thing.

Comment: If the account is deleted, it has no rep. If the account is merged into the questioner’s account, then it’s the same as a self answer (which gives no rep in itself).

Comment: @Laurel clarified that in Q. The sock-puppeteer is suspended and the sock-puppets are deleted (but their answer accept ticks remain).

Comment: We can't unaccept answers, but we can delete questions and answers, both actions remove the accept rep gained.

Comment: @SamuelLiew thanks for the reply, that might even be turned into an answer I think. As an aside, I don't know if you are familiar with my flag, the voting fraud seems to have been conducted on other sites too (using the association bonus). On it's own it's not fraud (at most one or two instances per site) but in view of the whole network, especially the now-deleted user, it's more of the same. Will you be passing that on to moderators on those sites?

Comment: You migh over-estimate what these short bans are supposed to accomplish.  First thing to do is to get that user out of the habit of thinking he can get away with it.  Done.  Bigger weapons are only brandished when he didn't get it repeatedly.  The damage he left in his wake is pretty limited, nobody is all that fooled about an accepted answer created by the same person that asked the question.  If you see obvious cases of a truly crappy solution being marked as the answer then just flag them, that's a quick zap from a moderator.

Comment: @HansPassant sure, it is if the mod is familiar with the case. How should I indicate this history? Especially if it's on another SE site (but between the same user and their sock-puppet on a different site). I'd basically be bad mouthing those other users. And the mods over there may not have a clue. In this case, all associated accounts are still active on the other SE sites. I cannot link to such a flag as I could to a review and the deleted account is already anonymised. It's something for the SO mods to communicate to their colleagues (IMHO).

Comment: Just don't under-estimate what a moderator already knows or can see, like you did. This isn't about retribution, it is about teaching users to use the site correctly.  Some users just need help with that, their parents were too busy to teach them.

Comment: @HansPassant what I saw was very obvious and the mods acted on that on SO. What remains isn't very obvious and without knowing about the SO case it's mere coincidence. It's like being the three-eyed raven but having to prove your case using what's in front of you. You know most of the pieces but you can't communicate them to the others. For now, I guess I might as well wait it out and see if more socks pop up (with this user) then flag again.

Comment: @HansPassant if they learn though, it can be undetectable for other users. Different names, no linked accounts, etc. I'm not sure if mods can dig deep enough to uncover that (looking at IP-addresses, more elaborate detective work). Who knows how much is going on nobody knows about.

Comment: Moderators are always familiar with the case, they handed out the ban.  Just don't worry about them slipping up, they never do.  What *they* can see is not what you can see, the moderator tools were optimized to eke out that kind of abuse.  It is fight club, they can't talk about it.

Comment: @HansPassant the moderator tools are limited to the site. I am pretty confident in saying that a mod from ELU cannot get as much information on an SO user as an SO mod. They can see hidden accounts (if they are linked), but that's pretty much it (or so I surmised).

Comment: Moderators from other sites in the network are allowed to talk to each other, though, and have dedicated private channels in which to do so. Thus, if you think there's a reason that the history of a user on another site should be taken into account, please let us know in the flag that you raise. Otherwise, we might miss it, since we don't routinely investigate off-site behavior. In general, we try to keep each site self-contained, not only for simplicity, but also out of a spirit of forgiveness. Of course, a pattern of behavior is always relevant in deciding on the appropriate course of action

Comment: @CodyGray Per my first flag *I suspect this account is a sockpuppet account of `red.`. This user asks different question `sic` on the network, gets good answers from different users but then `red.` posts a mediocre answer and it's accepted. Also, on superuser, and coffee.se (e.g. `red.`).  `red.` also shows up in those questions across the network. Please investigate.* Do with that what you will. I'm not saying that more action has to be taken, I just think it's worth thinking about. Especially this type of voter fraud (via accepts) could've easily been detected by some script much earlier.

Comment: @CodyGray I just stumbled on it by chance and I'm not even very bright. ;)

Comment: +1 Good policy question.

Comment: Okay, did a bit more clean-up there. It's worth noting that, although sockpuppetry is forbidden, there's nothing wrong with asking and answering your own question. So, other than the fact that the user did it through a sockpuppet, many of the Q&A are still legal and useful, so I'm not deleting those. The +2 from acceptance is not really a major abuse vector for sockpuppets, as if you really wanted those +2 points, you could just accept *any* answer you received. Flagging these things when you see them is always appreciated. You are our eyes and ears out there, no matter how bright you may be!

Comment: @CodyGray yea, it's the +15 given by a low-rep sock-puppet that starts them off. Over time, they'll get greedy and want more (up votes too) and then it should get obvious for mods looking into it (because it's the same account over and over again, either cross up votes or 8 accepts to get to the 15 rep marker for the up vote privilege).

Comment: They use the bounty system for reputation points laundering.

Comment: @PeterMortensen that only works if they have a high-rep account, right? The accept answer trick works by creating new accounts and answering their questions and accepting (so the bulk of the rep goes to their main account). In this case, the user already lost a few hundred rep from up votes made null (after deletion of the sock puppets). Much of the remaining rep (also hundreds of rep points) are still there from the accepts.

Comment: What is the problem with sock-puppet accounts If they are asking good questions and providing good answers? It almost seems like we would want to encourage that behavior to increase the SO library.

Comment: @java-addict301 it enables them to give themselves reputation. Effectively, if they have enough accounts and time on their hands they can basically control a lot of the other posts too. For example, it takes 5 close votes to close a post. Some more down votes to Roomba something. If you have many accounts you could potentially do a lot of that (and other things) to sabotage. In addition, many of the questions and answers in this case were very bad, much worse than answers by other users and their own were up voted (by sock) and accepted.

Comment: @JJJ thanks for the clarification - makes sense.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Do those answer ticks disappear after some time?

No, they don't.

Once a user is deleted as a sock puppet, only the votes of that user are deleted and not the answer acceptance. So they get to keep the +15 rep from getting an answer accepted, or +2 from accepting an answer by the sock. Moderators do not have any tool to accept/unaccept answers.

That said:

- On sock puppet deletion, we go through the list of answers that have been cross answered and delete them manually. (I sometimes leave an answer alone if it is of good quality, and let them enjoy the ill gained rep, in the interest of the larger community)
- Cross accepts/unaccepts in very large voting rings are usually escalated to the community team, who judge based on other unknown criteria and come to a decision. Site moderators are not involved in this.

Comment: Does this also mean that when a sockpuppet is deleted, their posts aren't automatically deleted too?

Comment: Their posts are deleted only if they are negatively scored. Otherwise they stay. (The same rule as with any account deletions)

Comment: I think merging accounts very efficiently handles fake rep, including accepts and double votes, is it used for sock puppets?

Comment: @gnat I think that'd take care of it, but there are a few issues with merges. 1. Moderators can't merge accounts. 2. Moderators can't escalate user merges unless there are a few exceptional cases. So, unless the user actually requests a merger with their sock, it is not possible.

Comment: very interesting, thank you! I didn't expect that merging is difficult for moderators but now that you explained it I see how it makes sense. From this perspective deletion indeed seems preferable over merging, even at cost of potentially leaking some fraudulent rep - I also posted [this request for stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385896/839601) to estimate how much rep can leak this way

Comment: Moderators haven't been allowed to merge for many years now, @gnat, ever since someone accidentally merged users that were not actually operated by the same person. That's dangerous for a number of reasons, not the least of which is giving someone access to someone else's personally identifying information. Now, merges have to be done *very* carefully. Instead of merging, deletion is the recommended course of action for sockpuppets. It works almost as well. The only real drawback is when the sockpuppet account posts useful content. Deletion orphans that, meaning they can't maintain it easily.

Comment: @Adriaan Related: [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594/253521)